# How to combine JSON formatted column data to strings in Bigquery table

Tags: string, split, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery column of JSON type and the data on the column looks like:

[{"day":"Monday","hours":[0,1,2,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]},{"day":"Saturday","hours":[0,1,2,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]},{"day":"Sunday","hours":[0,1,2,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]}]

I would like to combine the day and its respective hours value as shown below:

Monday:0,1,2,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23|Saturday:0,1,2,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23|Sunday:0,1,2,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Try [json_extract_array](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_array):

```
select
  json_value(one_day, '$.day') as day,
  trim(json_extract(one_day, '$.hours'), '[]') as hours
from UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY('[{"day":"Monday","hours":[0,1,2,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]},{"day":"Saturday","hours":[0,1,2,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]},{"day":"Sunday","hours":[0,1,2,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]}]','$')) as one_day
```

[image]